# SwiftUI: TapGesture prevents taps onto onDelete() action in list

Tags: list, swiftui, uitapgesturerecognizer

If I add both **onDelete()** to List Items and  `RootView().gesture(tap)` simultaneously to parent view of List then this TapGesture prevents tap-detection on Delete swipe action. Other Buttons are tappable in subviews.

Any idea how to solve this issue?